# How to read(-only) an Excel (with Python) from a network drive and leave the place as it was

Tags: excel, python-2.7, win32com

I have a little python (2.7) script reading in information from an excel file on a network drive. Works fine, but it was a little annoying during development, that after each script run the excel file was closed. This would be the intended behaviour, if the excel file was already closed when starting the script, but I was making edits to the excel to test the script. Furthermore I expect problems, if somebody already opened the workbook, because I don't automatically open the workbook as read-only copy (which would be fine, since I only read).

So the question is how in python do I fullfil the following requirement:

- if Excel was closed when starting the script, it must be closed after reading, otherwise not
- if the workbook was closed when starting the script, it msut be closed after reading, otherwise not
- If the workbook is opened by another user it shall be opened as read-only copy

?

Efforts so far:

besides googling I already searched this side for similar topics (e.g. "how do I check if Excel is open"). Most of the time the answers were about how to circumvent the core of the question, so they were no help to mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this exact problem a while back by first asking Excel for the list of already open workbooks. If the file that I wanted to open was already open, then I would set a flag "leaveOpenOnExit = True", otherwise leave it false, and open it. Then do the processing. Then at end, use the flag to decide whether to close the workbook.

Actually I also tested if Excel was already started when my script started, by using win32com's `GetActiveObject` which raises exception if none available, and then I set a flag accordingly. With that flag, on exit I would only close Excel if it was already open on startup of the script. Pattern is:

```
from win32com.client import GetActiveObject
from win32com.client import constants as comConst # will only contain COM constants if 
    # makepy.py has been run on Excel or if EnsureDispatch has been used once

try:
    excelRunsAtStart = True 
    excel = GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
except com_error:
    excelRunsAtStart = False
    excel = Dispatch("Excel.Application")

# use comApp...
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(excelPath, comConst.ReadOnly=1)
```

Comment: I would like to see some pseudocode ;-) Seriously, with that knowledge I could google it myself, but if you can spare the time. Any idea about opening an xls read-only, if it is already opened on a net drive? There shouldn't be a respective DOM-Object on my system I can look for

Comment: When I try something like "xl = win32com.client.GetObject(Class="Excel.Application")" I get an com_error instead of None. Works with try except, but if you said None it appears smelly

Comment: It's been a while and I no longer have the script, so I was going by memory. A short google search indicates that it must have been `GetActiveObject` with a `try/except`.

Comment: Read-only by wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(excelPath, ReadOnly=1) ... I'm done ;-) THX

Comment: Could you put     try:
        excelRunsAtStart = True
        excel = win32com.client.GetObject(Class="Excel.Application")
    except:
        excelRunsAtStart = False
        excel = client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')

Comment: And wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(excelPath, ReadOnly=1) in your code snippet, too, please. Comments might get deleted

Answer (score 1):

If you are only reading from the file, you may consider the [`xlrd`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) module instead of `win32com`. This is cross-platform and does not require Excel to work.

Comment: I didn't look at xlrd so far, because win32com was working fine for me, but this might be a reason to look into it. What are the limitations of xlrd (e.g. I guess you can't execute VBA macros of this workbook)?

Comment: I retract my question, answer is (partly) given in the tutorial (http://www.simplistix.co.uk/presentations/python-excel.pdf , page 4)

Comment: Windows is set in this company, but for private use (Linux) I'll have a look into xlrd and xlwt, THX